# How to extract numbers from a text field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a column in MySQL table which has phone numbers, but in unclean format i.e. there are double quotes, dashes and brackets, 
for ex:

```
[ "-", "7736562159" ]
[ "8177985242", "-" ]
```

I want to extract only the 'phone number'  part from this string. Is there any mysql function to do it?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756736/how-to-only-select-numeric-data-from-mysql

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: how to remove all non-alpha numeric characters from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942973/mysql-how-to-remove-all-non-alpha-numeric-characters-from-a-string)

Comment: It seems that several solutions are provided here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978147/how-do-you-extract-a-numerical-value-from-a-string-in-a-mysql-query

Comment: Some jobs are best handled in application level code. I would suggest that this is one of them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo could replace the non-numeric elements from the column using a query like

```
SELECT 
   REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`phone`, '-', ''), ' ', ''),'"','') AS `phone_number`
  FROM `table`;
```

Ref:
[Is there a way to select only integers of a field in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656127/is-there-a-way-to-select-only-integers-of-a-field-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brute force way, that should do what you want:

```
select (case when substring_index(col, '"', -2) + 0 > 0
             then substring_index(substring_index(col, '"', -2), '"', 1)
             when substring_index(col, '"', -3) + 0 > 0
             then substring_index(substring_index(col, '"', -3), '"', 1)
             when substring_index(col, '"', -4) + 0 > 0
             then substring_index(substring_index(col, '"', -4), '"', 1)
             when substring_index(col, '"', -5) + 0 > 0
             then substring_index(substring_index(col, '"', -5), '"', 1)
         end)
```

This breaks on the double quote character and tests if the value is a number.  If so, it then extracts it as a string.